# How to represent multiple positive buttons as CTA

Tags: interaction-design, buttons, icons

We have an extension that has two different actions: Yes and No. But these two actions come in two different flavours. Yes for the current page and Yes for the whole domain, meaning Yes for the current page and treat this as Yes for any future pages on this domain. Similar No for the current page and No for the whole domain.

1. I am using tick mark icon for Yes, Cross for No and ban icon for No
   for the whole domain. I am stuck at what icon could be the right choice for  Yes for the whole website. 
   [image: current icons and their meanings]
2. Also currently I am showing Yes for the current page as main CTA. I want to change the behaviour and make Yes for the whole domain as Yes.

I am planning to use a double tick mark (like WhatsApp_ for Yes for the whole domain option, but not sure if it does really convey the meaning.

Any suggestions on how should I go about this?

PS: This UI is a menu popped up by the browser extension.

I saw a few comments asking me the reason for having a negative option. Since this is a popup added inside the browser window by the extension if we don't have a negative option the popup will block the content inside the browser window. We thought of having a timer to close the popup but if the user moves away from the tab this might cause a problem. So we decided to have the negative option.

[image: Example Popup]

Comment: What is the user trying to solve here? What are the implications of Yes / No? And is there a central place to view / manage / edit the choices users are making? Any broader context is helpful.

Comment: Basically, the extension is to let the user take some notes on the pages he visits. But before he can take notes, he needs to save that page into his interested pages list. So Yes (Tick Mark) here means save this page, No (Cross) means don't save the page. and No (ban) means don't save any page from this website in future. 

Now I want to add an additional icon that lets the user save any page from the website.

Yes, user can manage the accepted (Yes to the domain - current feature) and ignored (No to the domain - already present) domains via a dashboard.

Comment: Is it possible to just focus on the 'Save' action, and disregard the negative (Don't save)? Is there a reason they have to explicitly 'not save'?

Comment: i don't get the needs. Surely it is simply save or no action. If I don't want to take a note, I simply don't. Why do I have to tell the system not to save something?

Comment: @MikeM Apologies for the lack of clarity. I have updated the post with reasons for having a negative option.  Thanks.

Comment: @colmcq Apologies for the lack of clarity. I have updated the post with reasons for having a negative option. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not completely understand the context, however, I assume that you are saying "Yes" or "No" to a Page, along with providing an option to the User to apply this decision to the whole domain too.

1. Keep only a "Yes" and a "No" CTA, and I hope the label of the button is clear enough to communicate the action being performed.
2. Include a "CheckBox" one line above these buttons which says "Apply this decision to the whole domain"

Answer (score 1):

> Any suggestions on how should I go about this?

Add text to the icons, to make it more clear. 
You can't expect people to understand what those buttons do without text.

Comment: Space is a constraint. I have just updated the post with a full screenshot of the popup. I guess the question above the buttons "Wish to grip this page?"  might help the users understand the context.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Pectoralis' answer, text is the most straight-forward thing you can use, instead of having users guess what the icons mean.

But your idea is actually also a valid option

> I am planning to use a double tick mark

But use it for **both**, positive and negative options. Something like this:

[image: the same buttons as in the question but with two icons for the bigger actions]

This is much easier to derive the logic for than to have completely different icons.
"One thing means action on this level, then two things must mean an action on a heavier/bigger scale."

Answer (score 0):

you don't need the don't save state. That's a default.

All you need are two icons: save page or save all pages.

Answer (score 0):

I propose a triple click icon-button:

- Click to toggle between Page/Domain
- Click Yes or Not to Page
- Click Yes or Not to Domain

[image]